How to redirect oauth callback with GET parameters to another view in Django
I am trying to handle a Google oauth2 callback for my app which uses subdomains for each customer. The user makes the authorization request from customer1.example.com/login, but Google requires a single callback page like www.example.com/callback for all possible subdomains. I encode the customer1 subdomain in the oauth state parameter. What I want to do is read the subdomain in one view and then redirect the entire callback, parameters and all, to a new page within the subdomain like customer1.example.com/callback. Here's how I'm accomplishing that now:
urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('callback/', views.gcallback, name='g_callback')
    ...
    ]

views.py
from subdomains import reverse #like reverse(), but supports subdomains
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def init_callback(request):

       state = request.GET.get('state')
       subdom = state.split('%')[0]

       #get parameter string from current uri
       auth_uri = request.build_absolute_uri()
       google_param_string = auth_uri.split('?')[1]     

       redir_url = reverse('users:g_callback', subdomain=subdom)

       #reappending GET parameters to URL
       redir_url = f'{redir_url}?{google_param_string}'

       return redirect(redir_url)

While this works, is there a way to effect the redirect simply to the new page with the original parameters? Something like:
def gcallback(request):
       subdom = request.GET.get('state').split('%')[0]
       redir_url = reverse('users:g_callback', subdomain = subdom)
       return redirect(redir_url, request)

Seems like there ought to be a way I am missing just to forward the request from one url to another without having to build the uri and strip the parameter string from it.
